# Trying to include template in the error 404 page

Tags: codeigniter

Im trying to get a error 404 page in the template which Im using, but it's not working. I have tried `MY_Exceptions` also.
There is view page called `error404` and code goes like this:

```
<h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

Just to display error msg.

Im trying to include the below line to display error in my template, but it's throwing error:

```
$this->load->view("pages/template.php");
```

What should I do to display customized error 404 in my template using codeigniter.

Comment: Just edit the error templates in view folder.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this, and pass `message` and `heading` like this :

```
$data['heading'] = 'heading';
$data['message'] = 'your message';

$this->load->view("pages/template",$data);
```

instead of this

```
$this->load->view("pages/template.php");
```

Your view `template.php`:

```
<h1><?php echo $heading;?></h1>
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

for more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view